# How to Generate an average regression table from a regression loop?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running a loop that produces a regression for each of 158 constituents of an index against the market.

My final coefficient is the mean of each coefficient in the regression loop. I am able to retrieve all the stats, however, I was wondering if it`s possible to generate a table with Statsmodels that displays the average stats. A so called "Meta Table" if you will.

Anyone got any suggestions?

This is the code I run. I create empty lists at the beginning and append the desired stats to them in the loop. In the end I covert them to data-frames and calculate the mean from there.

This code produces 158 tables.
Would there be any way of producing ONE table with the average stats from the 158 regressions?

```
Coefficients = []
Pvalues = []
Rsquared_adj = []
Bpagan = []
DBWatson = []
STD = []

for i in df:
    
    df["M"]=((df["Sum"]-df[i])/157) # Cross Sectional Mean Variable
    df["Mlag"]=df["M"].shift(1)
    df["Mlead"]=df["M"].shift(-1)
    df["Mtrn"]=(df["BBREIT Index"]-df["BBREIT Index"].shift(1))/df["BBREIT Index"].shift(1)
    df["Mtrn.lag"]=df["Mtrn"].shift(1)
    df["Mtrn.lead"]=df["Mtrn"].shift(-1)
    df.replace([np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
    df=df.fillna(0)
        
        
      
    y = df[i]
    x = df[["M","Mlag","Mlead","Mtrn.lag","Mtrn.lead"]]
    x = sm.add_constant(x)
    model = sm.OLS(y,x, missing = 'drop') 
    results = model.fit()
    print(results.summary())
    print(sm.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(results.resid, exog_het = x))
    print(durbin_watson(results.resid))
    
    
    # Filling the lists with the content specified
    coefficients=results.params 
    Coefficients.append(coefficients)
    
    pvalues=results.pvalues
    Pvalues.append(pvalues)
    
    rsquared_adj = results.rsquared_adj
    Rsquared_adj.append(rsquared_adj)
    
    bpagan = sm.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan(results.resid, exog_het = x)
    Bpagan.append(bpagan)
    
    std=results.bse
    STD.append(std)
    
    dbwatson = durbin_watson(results.resid)
    DBWatson.append(dbwatson)
    
    # CLearing the dynamic variables after use. Mostly for practical reuse-reasons
    Drop=df[["M","Mlag","Mlead"]]
    df.drop(columns=Drop, inplace=True)
```

[image: This table is produced for all of the 158 consituents. Is it possible to generate ONE table with average stats?]